# Get H.264 frame from UDP stream using jCodec

Tags: java, udp, h.264, jcodec

I am wondering how to get and decode a H.264 frame from a UDP live stream using jCodec. I see examples of how to get it from a file, but I need to get it from a live stream. I have the application receiving the live stream packets, but I need to know how to decode the packets and display the live stream.

Also, if there us a better way to do this than using jCodec please let me know. I looked for a while and that was the best I could find that is still actively maintained.

Comment: JCodec 2.6.0 is not able to start reading from the middle of a stream. I believe it works great when you load a file but when you feed it packets it doesn't work out of the box. I have made modifications so it parses the NALUs accordingly. But there is more work needed to take care of SPS/PPS units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using vlcj instead of jCodec. More information about vlcj can be found here:

http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/index.html

And a tutorial to get started can be found here:

http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html

Comment: can you please share with us the part of source code which is the response of your question

Comment: Unfortunately as this is something I did 3 years ago I am not sure I still have the source, but if I find it I'll try to post some code snippets later on.